# In scons, how can I inject a target to be built?

Tags: scons

I want to inject a "Cleanup" target which depends on a number of other targets finishing before it goes off and gzip's some log files.  It's important that I not gzip early as this can cause some of the tools to fail.

How can I inject a cleanup target for Scons to execute?

e.g. I have targets foo and bar.   I want to inject a new custom target called 'cleanup' that depends on foo and bar and runs after they're both done, without the user having to specify

```
% scons foo cleanup
```

I want them to type:

```
% scons foo
```

but have scons execute as though the user had typed

```
% scons foo cleanup
```

I've tried creating the cleanup target and appending to sys.argv, but it seems that scons has already processed sys.argv by the time it gets to my code so it doesn't process the 'cleanup' target that I manually append to sys.argv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.1.0.d20081104 of SCons, you can use the private internal SCons method:

```
SCons.Script._Add_Targets( [ 'MY_INJECTED_TARGET' ] )
```

If the user types:

```
% scons foo bar
```

The above code snippet will cause SCons to behave as though the user had typed:

```
% scons foo bar MY_INJECTED_TARGET
```

Comment: Undocumented features FTW! :-) I find I often just end up grepping the source for SCons when I hit these "unsolvable" problems...

Comment: Does this break when the --random flag is used? The order in which user-supplied targets are built is undefined, as far as I know.

Comment: I inject the target but have dependencies on other targets, so it fits snuggly in the graph.  Even if you do ``-random``, it will only randomize concurrent steps -- not steps which have dependencies on each other.  Dependencies are always satisfied before the depending target build command starts executing.

Comment: Do not use an undocumented "feature"; especially when there is a documented feature to use: BUILD_TARGETS.append('cleanup')

Answer (score 13):

you shouldn't use `_Add_Targets` or undocumented features, you can just add your cleanup target to `BUILD_TARGETS`:

```
from SCons.Script import BUILD_TARGETS
BUILD_TARGETS.append('cleanup')
```

if you use this documented list of targets instead of undocumented functions, scons won't be confused when doing its bookkeeping. This comment block can be found in `SCons/Script/__init__.py`:

```
# BUILD_TARGETS can be modified in the SConscript files.  If so, we
# want to treat the modified BUILD_TARGETS list as if they specified
# targets on the command line.  To do that, though, we need to know if
# BUILD_TARGETS was modified through "official" APIs or by hand.  We do
# this by updating two lists in parallel, the documented BUILD_TARGETS
# list, above, and this internal _build_plus_default targets list which
# should only have "official" API changes.  Then Script/Main.py can
# compare these two afterwards to figure out if the user added their
# own targets to BUILD_TARGETS.
```

so I guess it is intended to change `BUILD_TARGETS` instead of calling internal helper functions

Comment: This works great! But a follow-up question would be - how can I do this, when the target I want to add comes from the scanner? I.e. it gets produced at the runtime. I tried adding to BUILD_TARGETS, but that did not have any effect. Most likely SCons does not check that list after it started building.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have the gzip tool depend on the output of the log files. For example, if we have this C file, 'hello.c':

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And this SConstruct file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
env = Environment()
hello = env.Program('hello', 'hello.c')
env.Default(hello)
env.Append(BUILDERS={'CreateLog':
    Builder(action='$SOURCE.abspath > $TARGET', suffix='.log')})
log = env.CreateLog('hello', hello)
zipped_log = env.Zip('logs.zip', log)
env.Alias('cleanup', zipped_log)
```

Then running "scons cleanup" will run the needed steps in the correct order:

```
gcc -o hello.o -c hello.c
gcc -o hello hello.o
./hello > hello.log
zip(["logs.zip"], ["hello.log"])
```

This is not quite what you specified, but the only difference between this example and your requirement is that "cleanup" is the step that actually creates the zip file, so that is the step that you have to run. Its dependencies (running the program that generates the log, creating that program) are automatically calculated. You can now add the alias "foo" as follows to get the desired output:

```
env.Alias('foo', zipped_log)
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  The thing is, I'm doing a build flow that has pieces which I don't completely control, so I can't pre-register log files to be zipped because I don't know all the log files being created.